# Change mailer layout in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

How do I change the overall layout of an email in the method within a mailer?

Trying to essentially do this:

```
class AccountMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'mailer'

  def reset_password(user)
    layout 'simple_mailer'
  end
end
```

But that throws an error.

Basically I have a layout in `/app/views/layouts/simple_mailer.html.erb` that I'd like to use, but only in that one method.

I'm running Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 14):

The `mail` method can take a block that passes in a format object.

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  layout 'mailer'
  def password_reset(user)
   # uses the "mailer" layout
  end

  def special
    mail(to: "whomever") do |format|
      format.html { render(layout: false) } # no layout is used
      format.text # use the special.text.erb like normal
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass other options to **mail** block and specify what layout to be used, as below:

```
  class AccountMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    layout 'mailer'

    def reset_password(user)
      mail(to: 'test@gmail.com', subject: 'Sample Mail', from: "<test@gmail.com>") do |format|
        format.html { render layout: 'path_to/other_mailer_layout' }
      end
    end  
  end
```